# HTTP POST request works with Postman but not with my web application's JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch, rest, vs-web-site-project, http-status-code-415

I have a test environment in which I develop a website. This JavaScript code gives an error "415 unsupported media".

```
const sendData = async ()  => {
const result = await fetch(`${databaseURL}/categories`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        accept: 'application/json',
        'contet-type': 'application/json'
    }),
    body: {"Name":"", "isHTTPS":0, "DisplayName":""}
});
const json = await result.json();
```

Works fine with Postman. And GET request do actually work in the web application. Tryed several things like adding "no-cors" to the header and stringifying the body. Same result.
For my backend I am running a .NET C# application. I may have missed something. Can you help me? What additional information do you need for investigating my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the misspelled Content-Type header.

Your fetch function is saying it's sending JSON, but you still have to actually send JSON for the receiving end to decode it.
Use `JSON.stringify()` to turn your `body` object into JSON before sending it.

```
const result = await fetch(`${databaseURL}/categories`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
        accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "Name": "", 
      "isHTTPS": 0, 
      "DisplayName": ""
    })
});
```